# Service Fabric Reminders - Time remaining to trigger

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-service-fabric

Suppose I have a service fabric reminder which I registered via OnActivateAsync method. Now for these Service Fabric reminder via GetReminder method I can check whether a reminder already exists or not. But can I check when is this reminder scheduled to trigger next ?

For example I have registered a reminder with a period of 4 hours and it got triggered at 2PM ( schedule to trigger next at 6PM ). Now at 3:30 PM some of my other service want to know when is the next reminder scheduled. I can get this reminder via GetReminder method but I am unable to get the time remaining for its next execution.

Following this Doc - [Actor timers and reminders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-timers-reminders)

Answer (score 2):

Use the reminder due date. Add periods while the result is smaller than the current time.
The first time it is larger, the difference is the time remaining until it fires next.

Comment: Thanks for reply @LoekD. Correct me if I am wrong, in my knowledge dueTime stores the time remaining for execution of the reminder and not the time when the reminder was executed first. Suppose I gave dueTime as "TimeSpan.Zero", then it will store 0 in all of its values and not the current time. Right ?

Comment: [from the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.actors.runtime.iactorreminder.duetime?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_ServiceFabric_Actors_Runtime_IActorReminder_DueTime) :DueTime: Gets the time when the reminder is first due to be invoked. A value of negative one (-1) milliseconds means the reminder is not invoked. A value of zero (0) means the reminder is invoked immediately after registration.